# JQuery Mobile launching popup

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having an issue launching the popup from another javascript file, I boot the popup correctly form the index.html (had to put the javascript in the #main .

Now I can't launch it from a helper.js file (it loads the content properly as before but when I click the  it doesn't launch the popup, whilst I copied the same code and it works straight from the index.html.

```
content =  '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-up-c">'+
                '<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">'+
                '<div class="ui-btn-text">'+
                '<a id="btnChoicePopup" href="#" data-rel="popup" class="ui-link-inherit">'+
                '<img src="http://www.luc.edu/media/lucedu/sustainability-new/images/food_icon-1109x1089.png" class="ui-li-thumb">'+
                '<h3 class="ui-li-heading">Food</h3>'+
                '<p class="ui-li-desc">Im hungry!</p>'+
                '</a>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>'+
                '</div></li>';
$('.home').html(content).trigger("create");'
```

Any ideas? Here is the 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/zbznd/2).

Comment: Your jsFiddle example didn't work correctly, I made it work: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/DZ6DU/. But this is not going to help us help you. If you can, email me your example (my email is in my profile) and I will fix it for you.

Comment: @Gajotres I am cleaning up the code.. it will take a while, can you detail what changes did you do in the fiddle?

Comment: 1. Wrap your HTML inside a full HTMl page, it is not needed for jsFiddle but jQM code work better when it is tested as a full page. 2. var content  = ... and its next line is now part of a pagebeforeshow event. 3. $('.home').html(content).trigger("create"); is now $('.home').html(content);

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, I had the (#btnPopupChoice).click on another page (index.html) I just moved it right after the `$('.home').html(content).trigger("create");'` in the javascript file and worked.